# What Drupal setting controls prepending language codes to internal links?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

What Drupal setting controls the prepending of the language code when you hover over an internal link?

For example I have a node with a link to another internal node on it, and the hover link is:

http://localhost/drupal-7.43/fr/linked-page

I ask because I have another Drupal 7 website that doesn't prepend the language code and I'd like to turn it on.